# javascript strange comparison of strings

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have an ajax function that sends an email to somewhere and receives a response from the server from a json object with type = either success or error

```
$("#submit_btn").click(function(event) { 
    event.preventDefault();

    var post_data = {
        'email': $("#email").val()
    };
    $.post( "sendEmail.php", post_data ).done(function(response){
        if(response.type == 'success'){
            $("#sentmail").fadeIn("slow")
            setTimeout(function(){
                $("#mail").val("Enter your email here");

                $("#sentmail").fadeOut("slow")  
            },3000);
        }
        else{
            $("#sentmailfail").fadeIn("slow")
            setTimeout(function(){
                $("#mail").val("Enter your email here");

                $("#sentmailfail").fadeOut("slow")  
            },3000);
        }
    },"json")
});
```

The interesting part is that if I `console.log(response)` I get for instance `{"type":"success","desc":"something"}` and then straight after that `console.log( (response.type == "error") ) // TRUE`

if I take the consoled log from response and assign it to a variable for instance `a = {"type":"success","desc":"something"}` then `a.type == "error"` is false.

Can someone explain this?

Comment: The question I have is *when* do you try a `console.log(response)`?

Comment: `{"type":"success"` ... `type == "error"` um... you're clearly missing something, because your example is completely off.  It's impossible to tell what without a more thorough example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the output of `console.log(response)` is

```
{"type":"success","desc":"something"}
```

then `response` is most likely still a string (containing JSON), and strings don't have a `type` property:

```
> "foo".type == "error" // `undefined` is never equal to a string
false
```

Objects usually look differently in the console:

```
> console.log({"type":"success","desc":"something"})
Object {type: "success", desc: "something"} // in Chrome and Firefox at least
```

**Solution**: Parse the string first:

```
response = JSON.parse(response);
```

**Related to jQuery:**

I noticed that you intend to let jQuery parse the JSON for you, but you are passing `"json"` to the wrong function. You have to pass it to `$.post(...)`, not to `.done(...)`:

```
$.post("sendEmail.php", post_data, "json").done(...);
// instead of 
// $.post("sendEmail.php", post_data).done(..., "json");
```

Then you don't need to parse it manually.

---

Related: [Parse JSON in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4935632/218196)

Comment: I tried manually parsing the JSON but it didn't change anything, moving the ,"json" to the .post method didnt do anything too. I console.log the response right before the if statement
then I console.log( response.type ) // "error"
and then I console.log( response.type != "error" ) // true

Comment: What does `console.log( response.type.length )` output?

Comment: It outputs "Can't find property length of undefined". I wrote just JSON.parse(response) without assigning it to anything that was the problem. Thanks!